# How do you make clang++ not warn about variable length arrays?

Tags: c++11, clang++

I am compiling with clang++ -pedantic -Werror -std=c++11
C++11 does not support variable length arrays and so the compiler warns when they are used.
g++ supports the -Wno-vla option to stop it from doing this.
This doesn't appear to work in clang++, is there an alternative that does work?

Comment: Don't use '-pedantic -Werror' if you don't want warnings. Is this not obvious?

Comment: No because generally the more warnings the better. -pedantic enables lots of additional warnings and I just want to turn off one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
error: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Werror,-Wvla-extension]
  int a[argc];
       ^
1 error generated.
```

`clang++` helpfully tells you what flags generated the diagnostic. Just "invert" the flag, in this case: `-Wno-vla-extension`.